# Angular Material - How to attach custom directive attribute to md-list-item element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-material

I'm trying to attach a custom directive to items in an `ng-repeat` list created with `md-list`/`md-list-item`s, but because of the way angular material structures the `md-list-item` element when it's compiled in the DOM, nesting an absolute positioned button within for `ng-click` functionality, I can't find a way to actually attach the directive attribute to these as I could a normal `md-button` or similar.

I've tested the directive on other elements, where it's fine, and have tried attaching it directly to the `md-list-item`, but this obviously doesn't work.

Demonstrated in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2f6qscrp/513/.

HTML:

```
<md-list-item view-employee employee="employee" ng-click="viewEmployee($index)" ng-repeat="employee in main.employees">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the event listener to the button tag like this

```
angular.module('app').directive('viewEmployee', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            employee: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.find('button').bind('click', function(index, employee) {
                alert('viewEmployee(): ' + scope.employee.forename + ' ' + scope.employee.surname);
            })
        }
    }
})
```

I've also updated your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2f6qscrp/514/

Answer (score 0):

```
<md-list-item view-employee employee="employee"
              ng-click="viewEmployee($index)"
              ng-repeat="employee in main.employees">

    <b>{{employee.id}}</b>

    <span>{{employee.forename}} {{employee.surname}}</span>

</md-list-item>
```

Set the priority so that the directive runs after the `md-list-item` directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('viewEmployee', function() {
    return {
        priority: 10,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            employee: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(index, employee) {
                console.log('viewEmployee(): ' + scope.employee.forename
                             + ' ' + scope.employee.surname);
            })
        }
    }
})
```

The `md-list-item` directive removes click handlers from the element. By setting the priority of the `view-employee` directive to do postLink after the `md-list-item` postLink, the click handler avoids being removed and the directive works as expected.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de7zbfo9/).